# How to make interval date?

Tags: php, date

I have array with dates, for example:

```
$dates = array('2013-01-30', '2013-01-31', '2013-02-01', '2013-02-02', '2013-04-04', '2013-04-05', '2013-04-06');
```

http://codepad.org/Lnh0TYHW

How is the best way to make interval for these dates?
I would like receive:

```
$interval = array(
     array('first' => '2013-01-30', 'last' => '2013-02-02'),
     array('first' => '2013-04-04', 'last' => '2013-04-06')
);
```

first this is first date from array or first date not yet assigned. Last date this is date where next date is null. For example - 2013-02-02 - next should be 2013-02-03, but this is not in array, so 2013-02-02 is last in interval.

Comment: What is the relation of first and last? How did you pick up these dates?

Comment: We can't do anything without you giving us a relation.. What have you tried? and on what basis did you select which is first and which is last?

Comment: So basically, from an array of dates you wish to detect all contiguous date ranges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find contiguous date ranges, for each date you have to determine whether it follows the end of the last range. If it does, you expand that range; if not, you create a new range.

```
$dates = array('2013-01-30', '2013-01-31', '2013-02-01', '2013-02-02', '2013-04-04', '2013-04-05', '2013-04-06');

$ranges = array();
$current = 0;

foreach ($dates as $date) {
    if (isset($ranges[$current])) {
        // existing range
        if ($date == date('Y-m-d', strtotime("{$ranges[$current]['last']} +1 day"))) {
            $ranges[$current]['last'] = $date; // expand
        } else {
            ++$current; // move to a new range
        }
    }
    // create new range
    if (!isset($ranges[$current])) {
        // create new range
        $ranges[$current] = array('first' => $date, 'last' => $date);
    }
}

print_r($ranges);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample function and its usage, something I sometimes use myself. change the format in the function to make it look like your date

```
    function dateRange( $first, $last, $step = '+1 day', $format = 'Y/m/d' ) {

        $dates = array();
        $current = strtotime( $first );
        $last = strtotime( $last );

        while( $current <= $last ) {

            $dates[] = date( $format, $current );
            $current = strtotime( $step, $current );
        }

        return $dates;
    }

print_r( dateRange( '2010/07/26', '2010/08/05') );

Array (

[0] => 2010/07/26

[1] => 2010/07/27

[2] => 2010/07/28

[3] => 2010/07/29

[4] => 2010/07/30

[5] => 2010/07/31

[6] => 2010/08/01

[7] => 2010/08/02

[8] => 2010/08/03

[9] => 2010/08/04

[10] => 2010/08/05

)
```

skips weeks too:

```
print_r( dateRange( '2010/07/26', '2010/08/05', '+1 week') );

Array (

[0] => 2010/07/26

[1] => 2010/08/02

)
```

so in your case, you would be using it like this:

```
print_r(dateRange($interval[0]['first'], $interval[0]['last']));
```